# Connected App - Canvas integration

Tags: connected-apps

Recently we implemented connected app using the CANVAS SDK APIs , we are able to fetch the web page from an external application into SFDC - Visual force inside a Canvas - which technically encapsulates into an iframe i think.

functionality it is all working fine.

however on Chrome, Version 39.0.2171.95 m

the iframe rendering (canvas loading) is not smooth.
the iframe gets loaded partially or loads with distortion.

Note - the application we have integrated to - has several JS functions, JSF and other features built in to it.   (e.g. the auto-fill of text box) : the Auto-fill appears inside the canvas iframe - however the loading of those predictive auto fill text is not smooth or not clutterfree.  i.e. iframe gets loaded partially and gets distorted.

I checked for browser compaitbility issues and other session settings - but in vain.

any suggestions please ?

Thanks a lot
TJ

Comment: ON IE 8  - the above feature works fine (i.e. Jquery, JSF - they all seem to work fine).  
On IE 9 - JSF / Jquery does not get executed hence we need to run in Compatibility mode.

I am trying something similar in Chrome - but not sure if I can run Chrome browser in previous versions compability mode !!

Answer (score 2):

Chrome, Version 39.0.2171.95 m has all sorts of rendering issues when dealing with `iframe`

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=444948
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=441667
https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=444948

You can try various compatibility modes by using an extension such as [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/user-agent-switcher-for-c/djflhoibgkdhkhhcedjiklpkjnoahfmg?hl=en-US).

Comment: I tried the extension you recommended - but it only acts as spoof to simulate IE , IOS and other browsers.   I wanted to try our connected app with different older / latest versions of Chrome.  kindly suggest.